# How to generate TCP/UDP packet using Python in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, sockets

In Linux, I can generate a TCP/UDP packet with the following command.

```
echo "hello world" > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1337
echo "hello world" > /dev/udp/127.0.0.1/31337
```

I've been searching a similar way to do it in Python, but it's not as simple as Linux.

1. https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication
2. [How To Generate Tcp,ip And Udp Packets In Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196886/how-to-generate-tcp-ip-and-udp-packets-in-python)

I'm using Python 3.5.1 in Windows and try the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 1337
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print ("received data:", data)
```

I've also performed a packet capture to see this packet and was able to see TCP 3 way handshake followed by FIN packet.

So, my questions are:

1. Why "Hello, World!" message did not appear in Wireshark (Follow TCP Stream)?

I can see the message when I run `echo "hello world" > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1337` in Linux.

2. I also get the following error when running the code.

I googled the error and found similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-when-writing-t), but the code is different.

Please let me know what's wrong with the code and how to fix it.

```
C:\Python\Codes>tcp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Codes\tcp.py", line 12, in <module>
    s.send(MESSAGE)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

C:\Python\Codes>
```

3. Is this the simplest way to generate TCP packet in Python?

Comment: Wireshark isn't likely going to read anything over the localhost (127.0.0.1) adapter.

Comment: It's as simple to do in Python _on linux_ as from the shell on linux: `with open('/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/31337, 'wb') as port31337: port31337.write(b'hello world')`.

Comment: Also, this doesn't "generate a TCP package", it writes to a TCP data stream, which could generate 1 packet or 5 packets or half a packet. Normally, in TCP, you don't worry about individual packets (when that's important, you usually want UDP instead); if you do, you need a lower level than the basic `SOCK_STREAM` API.

Comment: Thanks @selbie, I've also tried this on remote server. I can see the packet but "hello world" message is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
s.send(MESSAGE)
```

This:

```
b = s.send(MESSAGE.encode("utf8"))
s.send(b)
```

Comment: Why `bytearray` instead of just using `encode`? He doesn't need to mutate the bytes or expand the array anywhere, does he?

Comment: Thanks @selbie. It works! I can see the message on both Wireshark & nc listener I created on remote server.

Unfortunately, I'm getting another error.

`  File "C:\Python\Codes\tcp.py", line 13, in <module>
    s.send(b)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'`

Full code here. 

https://pastebin.com/nbBFftTt

https://pastebin.com/nbBFftTt

Answer (score 0):

As the traceback says, it is a TypeError: a bytes-object like is required, not a str

so, you can use `.encode()` on a string to get a bytes-object like and then `.decode()` to get back the string.

```
MESSAGE = 'Hello, World!'
encoded = str.encode(MESSAGE)     # b'Hello, World!'
decoded = encoded.decode()        # 'Hello, World!'
```

here, this link, you might find it useful. [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Hope it helps.